# Realm browser is not opening because of another process

Tags: swift, realm

I am getting this error message when I want to start up the Realm browser:

'Realm file is currently open in another process which cannot share access with this process. All processes sharing a single file must be the same architecture. For sharing files between the Realm Browser and an iOS simulator, this means that you must use a 64-bit simulator.'

I closed all applications and even re-started the computer, so which process is this that is running there? It's been working all fine before.

Comment: If you've made sure that there's no other process running, try manually deleting lock files.

Comment: great, that worked, thx, can you please make your response to an answer so that I can tick this off as resolved. Thx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check which process is using a file. On MacOS and Linux you can do it this way (replace `myfilename` with your actual database name):

```
lsof | grep myfilename.realm
```

You can kill the process using the file if needed.

If no process is running and the error still appears, you can safely **delete** the `myfilename.realm.lock` file.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to open the file after stopping the app running on simulator/device.