# Can't Open Realm Studio After Update - Realm file is currently open in another process - Mac & Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have no idea how to fix this.

Realm Studio notified me of an update last night. I didn't think anything of it and updated. Since then I can not open any Realm Files inside of Realm Studio.

> Realm file is currently open in another process which cannot share access with this process. All processes sharing a single file must be the same architecture.

I thought it was an issue with Realm also needing to be updated. So I updated RealmSwift from 4.4.0 to 4.4.1. That didn't work.

I found this and gave it a try: (It didn't work)
[Realm browser is not opening because of another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198410/realm-browser-is-not-opening-because-of-another-process)

So I deleted the entire Core Simulator Folder and reinstalled it. That also didn't work.

I'm out of ideas on how to fix this.

Note: Realm still seems to work in the simulator. I just can't open the file into Realm Studio.

Comment: Which simulated device are you using?

Comment: I was using multiple. Mostly 11 Pro Max and SE (2gen) - Deleting RealmStudio and reinstalling it fixed the issue.

Comment: I have completely deleted ReamStudio and installed the latest RealmStudio from this link solved my issue. Now i can see the live changes in RealmSwift.        
                                                                                                                                
Link: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/studio/install/#:~:text=.AppImage-,MacOS,.dmg,-Windows

Answer (score 2):

Deleting RealmStudio and redownloading and installing fixed the issue.

Comment: It was a bit of an adventure. To be fair I have no idea what I'm doing. But its solved now and I can get back to work! Thanks for being apart of the journey!

Comment: Updating my Realm packages and rebuilding the app solved the problem for me. Must be a really generic error message!